# How do I set colors for specific sections of my background?

Tags: html, css, background

I'm currently attempting to set my background color for a specific section of my page background.  The idea is to have about 1/5 or 1/4 of the top section of the page be one color, while the whole remaining bottom is a separate color.  I've considered using gradients to do it, but I don't know how to set the specific stopping section via CSS3.

Any ideas of how I could get this done using CSS3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [gradient generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#fb83fa+25,7ceacd+25,7ceacd+100;Custom)

```css
html, body {
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #fb83fa;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fb83fa 25%, #7ceacd 25%, #7ceacd 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(25%,#fb83fa), color-stop(25%,#7ceacd), color-stop(100%,#7ceacd));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fb83fa 25%,#7ceacd 25%,#7ceacd 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fb83fa 25%,#7ceacd 25%,#7ceacd 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fb83fa 25%,#7ceacd 25%,#7ceacd 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fb83fa 25%,#7ceacd 25%,#7ceacd 100%);
}
```

Or you could ditch the gradients and use a pseudo element...

```css
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: #7CEACD;
}

body:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 25%;
    background: #fb83fa;
}
```

Comment: Would I be able to use the first option to have the color at the top 20% of the page meld into the bottom %80 similarly to using a gradient?  I was attempting to recreate my idea in the gradient generator, but was a bit lost as to what I was doing.

Comment: Like this? http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#fb83fa+25,7ceacd+100;Custom

Comment: Pretty much.  The colors and locations need a bit of switching around, but I've got that handled.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use separate divs to represent the different sections and then use height: 20vh to represent 20% of the current view height.

```
.top {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 20vh;
}

.bottom {
    background-color: red;
    height: 80vh;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/goerfjyf/1/

I have also included a container div to hold the rest of your content basically acting in the same way as the body usually does.

Answer (score 0):

Without needing to figure out the stopping points, you could use a gradient with just 2 identical colours and use `background-size` to set its height.

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
}
body{
    background:linear-gradient(0deg,#f00,#f00) no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 25%;
}
```